# Open Full-Screen Modal Outside Plugin Box in Garden

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, zelle

I am currently developing a custom plugin for Banno, and I've encountered a challenge with rendering a modal. The modal is currently confined within the plugin box, and I want it to open in full-screen mode.
Here is a visual representation of the current state: [Current Modal Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afnsw.jpg)

Could anyone provide guidance or suggest modifications to the code to ensure that the modal opens in full-screen mode, detached from the boundaries of the plugin box?
Appreciate any assistance or insights into resolving this issue!

I'm currently facing challenges in achieving this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for plugin cards to modify the Banno UI/UX nor a way to open arbitrary new windows per the [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) page.

Per that page, you may want to consider [activating the expanded view from the card face](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face).

An alternative use case is to open an [embedded web browser link via the Plugin Bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/#embedded-web-browser-links).